# How can I mark the intersections on the x axis of the following graphs?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

Im trying to reproduce the following graph:
[image]

I have the parabolas graphed, but I want to indicate the intercepts with the x axis by some point or cross, also I want to eliminate the numbers and the little lines that mark them. I have this:
[image]

Thanks in advance. Im new to mathematica so...

Comment: "I have the parabolas graphed" - add the settings `Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[4]` as a starting point.

Comment: thankssssssssss

Comment: Next time, please include code for any pictures you made with *Mathematica* instead of having people guess what you did.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
eqs = {(x + 5)^2 - 130, (x - 2)^2 - 130};
intercepts = NumericalSort[x /. Solve[Or @@ Thread[eqs == 0], x]];
Plot[
 eqs,
 {x, -21, 16},
 AxesStyle -> White,
 Background -> Black,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {n, \[Epsilon]},
 FrameStyle -> White,
 FrameTicks -> None,
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[White, AbsolutePointSize[6]],
 PlotStyle -> Red,
 Ticks -> None,
 Epilog -> {
   White,
   MapThread[
    Text[Subscript[n, #2], {#1, 
       4}, {Sign[#2 - 2.5] 2, -1}] &, {intercepts, 
     Range[Length[intercepts]]}]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Plot of parabolas with zeroes shown.]

I've sort of tried to "automate" finding the zeroes and plotting the labels, but it will probably still require a bit of manual tweaking to get the labels right. Thanks to J. M.'s ennui for the `Mesh/MeshFunctions/MeshStyle` solution. Since I'm already calculating the intercepts, one could also just use those, but I liked the `Mesh` solution better.

I'm using `Epilog` to add the text to the plot. The `Sign[#2 - 2.5]2` is just there so that the first two zeroes use -2 as their x-offset and +2 for the second two zeroes. What looks good will depend a lot on what equations you're plotting, so the positioning may vary.

Comment: "Since I'm already calculating the intercepts, one could also just use those, but I liked the `Mesh` solution better." - if you're really determined to avoid redundancy, you could extract the positions of the intersection points from (a preliminary version of) the plot before putting in other stuff, but then you now need to do things in stages.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui I guess that would involve generating the plot and spelunking for the mesh points? I really wish I was better with pattern matching and `Cases` and that sort of thing. Some of my favourite solutions from other users seem to involve those sorts of things. I guess I will need to practice them; start simple and build from there.

Comment: Right, I'd be using `Cases[]` + `Normal[]` for that extraction (usually): `Cases[Normal[g], Point[{x_, y_}] :> x, Infinity]` (with the assumption that the only points added come from `Mesh`/`MeshFunctions`). A lot of people here have done this too, so if you want practice, you could try finding those answers to study them. ;) (I should also say that one of the upvotes came from me.)

Answer (score 2):

We can use a *function* as the option setting for `MeshStyle` to add labels to mesh points without having to post-process:

```
Plot[{(2 x + 2) (2 x - 1), (2 x + 1) (2 x - 2)}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> ({Directive[White, AbsolutePointSize[10]], #, White, 
   MapIndexed[Text[Style[Subscript[n, {1, 3, 2, 4}[[#2[[1]]]]], 
       18, White], #,{{-2, 2}[[Mod[#2[[1]], 2, 1]]], -1}] &,  #[[1]]]} &), 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style[ϵ, 16, White], None}, {Style[n, 16, White], None}}, 
 Background -> Black, FrameStyle -> White, AxesStyle -> White, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Use `Mesh -> {{5}}` to get

[image]